# ps start_time as timestamp

Tags: linux, shell, awk, ps

I'm currently using the `ps` command to monitor some processes. However, I would like like to have the time output as a Unix timestamp.

The command I am using:

```
ps -eo class,s,user,pid,pcpu,stat,start_time,cputime,args --sort=class | \
  awk '$1 != "RR" && $1 != "FF" {print $0; next } 0'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `etimes` option (elapsed time since the process was started, in seconds) and `awk`'s `systime()` function that returns the current timestamp in seconds.

Suppose the 7th column is `etimes`, then the AWK expression should look like this:

```awk
NR == 1 ? "TIMESTAMP" : systime() - $7
```

Example:

```
ps -eo class,s,user,pid,pcpu,stat,etimes,cputime,args --sort=class | awk \
  '$1 != "RR" && $1 != "FF" {print $0, NR == 1 ? "TIMESTAMP" : systime() - $7 }'
```

*Sample Output*

```
CLS S USER       PID %CPU STAT ELAPSED     TIME COMMAND TIMESTAMP
TS  S root         1  0.0 Ss      1717 00:00:01 init [3] 1479001705
TS  S root         2  0.0 S       1717 00:00:00 [kthreadd] 1479001705
TS  S root         3  0.0 S       1717 00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0] 1479001705
```

If you want to replace the seventh column, you can just override the `$7` variable: `$7 = systime() - $7`.

If the result of the command is supposed to be parsed further, I would remove the headers with `--no-headers` option, e.g.:

```
ps --no-headers -eo class,s,user,pid,pcpu,stat,etimes,cputime,args \
  --sort=class | awk '$1 != "RR" && $1 != "FF" { $7 = systime() - $7; print }'
```

*Sample Output*

```
TS S root 1 0.0 Ss 1479001705 00:00:01 init [3]
TS S root 2 0.0 S 1479001705 00:00:00 [kthreadd]
TS S root 3 0.0 S 1479001705 00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
```

Note, there is no need for the [`next`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html#Next-Statement) statement in your script, since its purpose is to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record, and there are no statements (pattern-action pairs) to skip at the end of the script.

Comment: Actually there is another script-element after `next` in the Q, namely `0`. But it never matches, so there's still no need for the `next`.

Comment: for CentOS 6.7 it's etime not etimes